# How to find referenced documents in a collection (multilevel query / join) in mongodb using mongoid in rails app?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoid, document, nosql

It is all about `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation and queries in `mongodb` using `mongid3` in rails application.

I have `class A` and `class B`, say:

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bs
end
```

and

```
class B
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :as
end
```

Now instantiate 3 `a`-s and 3 `b`-s:

```
a1 = A.create()
a2 = A.create()
a3 = A.create()

b1 = B.create()
b2 = B.create()
b3 = B.create()
```

Now reference them one in another, e.g:

```
a1.bs.push([b1, b3])
a2.bs.push([b2, b3])
a3.bs.push(b2)
```

So:

```
b1.as.all
 => [<#A _id: 1000000000000001>] # i.e. a1

b2.as.all
 => [<#A _id: 1000000000000002>, <#A _id: 1000000000000003>] # i.e. a2, a3

b3.as.all
 => [<#A _id: 1000000000000001>, <#A _id: 1000000000000002>] # i.e. a1, a2
```

Similar for `a`-s:

```
a1.bs.all
 => [<#B _id: 2000000000000001>, <#B _id: 2000000000000003>] # i.e. b1, b3

a2.bs.all
 => [<#B _id: 2000000000000002>, <#B _id: 2000000000000003>] # i.e. b2, b3

a3.bs.all
 => [<#B _id: 2000000000000002>] # i.e. b2
```

Now I want get those `a`-s which have `b`-s, which have

- a3:

  - a1 has b1, b3 which have: [[a1],[a1, a2]] => [a1, a2] => don't include a1
  - a2 has b2, b3 which have: [[a2, a3],[a1, a2]] => [a1, a2, a3] => include a2
  - a3 has b2, which has [[a2, a3]] => [a2, a3] => include a3

    => [a2, a3] => [<#A _id: 1000000000000002>, <#A _id: 1000000000000003>]
- both a1 and a2:

  - a1 has b1, b3 which have: [[a1],[a1, a2]] => [a1, a2] => include a1
  - a2 has b2, b3 which have: [[a2, a3],[a1, a2]] => [a1, a2, a3] => include a2
  - a3 has b2, which has [[a2, a3]] => [a2, a3] => don't include a3

    => [a1, a2] => [<#A _id: 1000000000000001>, <#A _id: 1000000000000002>]
- don't include a1

  - a1 has b1, b3 which have: [[a1],[a1, a2]] => [a1, a2] => include a1
  - a2 has b2, b3 which have: [[a2, a3],[a1, a2]] => [a1, a2, a3] => include a2
  - a3 has b2, which has [[a2, a3]] => [a2, a3] => don't include a3

    => [a3] => [<#A _id: 1000000000000003>]
- etc.

I thought it would be easy:

```
 A.all.where("b.id" => a1._id).count
  => 0
```

or

```
 A.all.where(:"bs.id" => a1._id).count
  => 0
```

or

```
 A.all.where(:"b.id" => "1000000000000003").count
  => 0
```

But nope...

**TLDP:** how to find documents which have collections which have desired documents? (say multilevel query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query for finding if HasMany (or HABTM) relation has relationshipt with another side (belongs_to or HABTM) is :

```
A.in(b_ids: [b1.id])
# return criteria for : All A's that b_ids has b1.id
```

It also works this way :

```
A.where(:b_ids.in => [b1.id])
```

If you want to query multiple items of array you must use mongodb `$all` operator :

```
A.where(:b_ids.all [b1.id,b2.id])
# return criteria for : All A's that b_ids has b1.id and b2.id
```

[Mongoid/Origin.Selection Documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#standard)

[MongoDB $in operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

[MongoDB $all operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)